# How does Bloomberg arrive at stub rate for swaps/floaters?

Tags: fixed-income, bond, pricing, bloomberg, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate initial stub rate ( 'Index to' in the image ) for the following FRN pricing example.

- Fixes on 2016/11/30
- 1m : 0.623670
- 2m : 0.742500
- 3m : 0.93417

Please be as specific as possible ( particularly day count convention ).

[image: 3m Floater]

Comment: Did you try asking Bloomberg help desk?

Comment: I did. Was told to look up documentation, which is nothing but minimal description of what Current Index is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic money markets arithmetic. Using day count convention ACT/ACT,

`01 Dec 2016 to 13 Jan 2017 is 43 days,`

`(43-30)/(60-30)*(2m Libor - 1m Libor)+(1m Libor)`

`= 0.675163`

Comment: Matches bloomberg perfectly except when the settlement date is holiday. Though it isn't a proper use case, bloomberg still gives some number which i would like to match. Any ideas there?

Comment: It depends on Bloomberg's method; you may need fwd Libor rates?

Comment: Uses latest fix. No projection.

Comment: Above formula works for Act/360 floaters